# MySQL retrieved data is different than expected

Tags: c#, mysql

I am using C# and MySql(myphpadmin) to create an Inventory System wherein there are search functions to retrieve data and put them in the DataGridView. However, the function I have created does not work as intented when I am sure that my query is correct since I literally copy pasted it from myphpadmin query.

Below is the code I used to make the query and retrieve data.

```
// Search transaction
public void searchTransaction(DataGridView table, String ID, String filter)
{
    // Prepare string query
    conString = String.Format("select * from tbl_transactionhistory where {0} like @ID", filter);

    try
    {
        // Connect to database
        cmd = new MySqlCommand(conString, connect());
        // Add values to parameters
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", "%" + ID + "%");
        // Instantiate reader
        MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        // Verify data
        if (dr.Read())
        {
            // Create a medium to store data from the database
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(dr);
            table.DataSource = dt;
        }
        else
        {
            table.DataSource = null;
        }
    }
    catch (MySqlException e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

The table in the database is named `tbl_transactionhistory` and the following are fields and types

```
Transaction_No int(11)
Cust_No int(11)
Cust_Name varChar(255)
Product_Name int(6)
Price_Issued decimal(5,2)
Trans_Date date
```

The `filter` parameter in the function receives only two: `Transaction_No` and `Cust_No`

I tried removing the `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue` and replaced it with literally inserting variables in the `conString` but it still does not work. My theory is that the query is compared with the `Trans_Date` since when I input digits `0, 2, 3` in any order; it always show those with 2023 in the `Trans_Date`. But I do not understand why.

Comment: Ensure that the `filter` variable contains the correct column name (`Transaction_No` or `Cust_No`) when passed to the `searchTransaction` method.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @AmitMohanty but I really do. I even tested putting the field itself as the argument yet it still does not give the proper results.

Comment: ***My theory is that the query is compared with the Trans_Date...***, however, the condition for comparing with `Trans_Date` hasn't been added. Could you please clarify this further?

Comment: For example, I have 202330001 - 5 records in the Transaction_No and the Transaction_No from 202330002 - 202330004 has 2023-mm-dd in the Trans_Date. When I put the digits "0, 2, 3" in any order; it shows the mentioned records but never the 2023300001 and 2023300005. Therefore I'm theorizing that somehow, it compares with Trans_Date.

Comment: You could enable the [general_log](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/query-log.html#:~:text=To%20disable%20or%20enable%20the,name%20of%20the%20log%20file.) (`SET GLOBAL general_log = 1;`) and tail the log to see what is being passed to MySQL.

Comment: Have you tried perform the exact query either from the MySQL command-line or through a workbench & seeing if you get the results you expect from your code. Then you at least know whether it is more likely to be a coding or querying problem.

Comment: I have solved the problem. It was the dr.Read() in the if statement. Since the first row was already read, only the next row in the database are shown. Therefore, the solution I did was made a DataReader whose sole purpose is to check if the table is empty then create another instance to read and load the rows in the DataGridView assuming the 1st DataReader is true.

Thanks for the help!